# Where to put downspout?

Tags: drainage, gutters, rain

Reference image below.

The image shows the back of our house where the water currently falls next to our house, and the pit it’s starting to make on the ground (circled).

The side “yard” on that part of the house is about 7 feet wide. I don’t want to direct water to the fence because of fence rot (we’re in the processing of replacing the fence in the photo), and because it would also potentially flood into the neighbors yard. The peaked roof won’t let us direct it to to the front of the house. The driveway is kitty corner from this problem spot so not really an option either. We could send it into the backyard but we already have flooding issues in the backyard, and directly behind me in the photo is a large tree. Afraid if we dump the water there we’ll eventually make the tree unstable, but maybe I’m overthinking it/don’t know what I’m talking about. I also don’t have french drain, ditch digging money at the moment.

Any ideas? I’m in North Dallas if that’s helpful (get a lot of that Plains rain!).

[image: back of house]

Comment: Having water dumped beside foundation is not good.  The extra roof does not help since the water from both is collected in a single point.  You want downspout to carry the water away from the house quite a bit, either under or over ground.  The side is a bit short, so somewhere down the back should work.

Comment: Synopsis: I don't want to put the water anywhere it could go, I have said "no" to all the options, so I'd like a miracle from the internet...

Comment: You need to give us more pics.  Front yard facing the street from the gate, front yard facing the house from the street, back yard facing away from the house, back yard facing the house.